# JS overwrite user input with a new user input

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. How do I let the user keep reusing the input field so they can enter different names, and the text in the textarea will always change to whatever is being entered in the field?

```js
function saveName() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var snippet = document.getElementById('text'+i).value;
    const result = snippet.replaceAll(/name/gi, name);
    document.getElementById('text'+i).innerHTML = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <input class="name" type="text" id="name" maxlength="100" value="" placeholder="Enter name"><br>
  <button class="save" id="saveName" onclick="saveName();">Save</button>
</div>

<textarea class="box" id="text1">Hello name</textarea>
<button class="btn1" style="vertical-align:top;">Copy</button>

<textarea class="box" id="text2">Welcome name</textarea>
<button class="btn2" style="vertical-align:top;">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = snippet.replaceAll(/name/gi, name);
```

You are replacing the string **'name'** with the value of the input.
This works the first time, as the text in the `<textarea>` contains the word 'name'.
The second time, however, the text will most likely be something like 'Hello John'.

My suggestion would be to replace to complete value of the `<textarea>`.

```
function saveName() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    document.getElementById('text'+i).textContent = 'Hello ' + name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, in my case this wouldn't work because I have many textareas with much longer text. I can't "hardcode" all the text using `.textContent`. So I need to find a way to detect the user input within that text to then replace it with a different input.

Comment: You could create a template for the text, and put a substitute in places where the user input should go. For example: 'The user who wrote this is {name}.'.
In saveName() you would take the template and replace every {name} with the user input.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would select the textareas with querySelectorAll, so you can get an array of all of them.  That way it will handle them dynamically, regardless of how many you have.  Then replace the full textContent with Hello + name.

```
function saveName() {
    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    for (inputField of document.querySelectorAll('textarea.box')) {
        inputField.innerText = inputField.textContent = `Hello ${name}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, in my case, using `textContent` wouldn't work because I have many textareas with much longer text. I can't "hardcode" all the text in the JS. So I need to find a way to detect the user input within that text to then replace it with a different input.

Comment: A textarea is meant to be editable.  What is the use-case for you to have a bunch of non-editable text within many textareas?  Would it not be more appropriate to place it outside of the elements?